# NuGet pack fails with "Warning as Error" exceptions

Tags: nuget

I'm trying to use NuGet to create a package from a csproj file.  Command line like:

```
nuget pack MyProject.csproj
```

The build fails in a dependent project with multiple "Warning as Error" exceptions even though all the project files are set to "Treat warnings as errors": None

Again, to clarify the build is failing in a dependent project (not the project in the command line).  The dependent projects are referenced "by project" not by "by file".

The project are VS2010 SP1, and I just ran "nuget update"...

Is this a known issue?  Any work around?  Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a bug. Properties from the project aren't being flowed correctly.

Comment: I'm assuming it's a bug too... Work around: Fixed all the warnings... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has been fixed. If you update NuGet.exe, it won't compile the project by default. Instead, you need to specify the -Build option.

```
nuget.exe MyProject.csproj -Build
```